# Android: BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray - reduce image quality

Tags: java, android, bitmap, jvm, out-of-memory

This is my use case:

```
ByteArray ba; // Some value is assigned here
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(ba, 0, ba.length);
```

Because the `ByteArray` object is to large, an `OutOfMemoryError` exception is thrown at the second line, when doing:

`BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(ba, 0, ba.length);`

Already tried:

```
ByteArray ba; // Some value is assigned here
BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
options.inSampleSize = 4; //or whatever value
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(ba, 0, ba.length, options);
```

The problem with this solution is that, using `inSampleSize` attribute, it avoids the `OutOfMemoryError` exception, but the **bitmap** size (dimensions: width x height) is reduced.

Instead I'm looking for something similar to this:

`bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 50, stream);`

At this example the **quality** of the bitmap is reduced, **BUT its size** is still the same. When I display it in an `ImageView`:

`iv.setImageBitmap(bitmap);`

It occupies the same space as the original, but with half quality.

The problem is, that in my case I cannot use `bitmap.compress` because my bitmap is **null**. That is, the `compress` method can be used **after** you have a valid `Bitmap` object, which is not my case.

**Question:**

Is there any solution using `BitmapFactory.Options` which can lead to the same result as `bitmap.compress`: lower `quality`, same `dimensions`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there any solution using BitmapFactory.Options which can lead to the same result as bitmap.compress: lower quality, same dimensions?

Not really. A `Bitmap` is uncompressed by its very nature.

> The problem is, that in my case I cannot use bitmap.compress because my bitmap is null.

You are confusing an encoded JPEG image with a `Bitmap`. An encoded JPEG image is compressed. A `Bitmap` is not. A `Bitmap` *always* consumes memory based on the width, height, and the number of bits per pixel.

You could use a different number of bits per pixel. `BitmapFactory` uses `ARGB_8888` (32 bits/pixel). You could switch to `RGB_565` (16 bits/pixel), if your image has no alpha channel and you can live with the reduced range of colors.

Otherwise, your only option is to reduce the size (width and height) of the image.

Comment: This might be a good solution is some cases. Switching from `ARGB_888` to `RGB_565` reduces the size by more than half.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot compress the bitmap as you want.

You may already know this - But, Yes! you can find the appropriate inSampleSize by this method to maintain the quality based on the size.

```
public static int calculateInSampleSize(
            BitmapFactory.Options options, int reqWidth, int reqHeight) {
    // Raw height and width of image
    final int height = options.outHeight;
    final int width = options.outWidth;
    int inSampleSize = 1;

    if (height > reqHeight || width > reqWidth) {

        final int halfHeight = height / 2;
        final int halfWidth = width / 2;

        // Calculate the largest inSampleSize value that is a power of 2 and keeps both
        // height and width larger than the requested height and width.
        while ((halfHeight / inSampleSize) >= reqHeight
                && (halfWidth / inSampleSize) >= reqWidth) {
            inSampleSize *= 2;
        }
    }

    return inSampleSize;
}
```

This method is picked from [Android Loading Large images efficiently](https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/graphics/load-bitmap).

You can read more about handing Bimaps [here](https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/graphics)